# Passing $_GET into mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this

```
$name = $_GET['fullname'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$gender = $_GET['gender'];

$query = "INSERT INTO main (name, username, password,gender) VALUES (" . $name . "," .  $username . "," . $password . ", " . $gender . ");";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

and I pass in the url as:
`http://my.website.com/submit_user_info.php?fullname=myfullname&username=myusername&password=mypassword&gender=m`

If I rewrite the `$query` to have hardcoded values such as `VALUES (myfullname,"...etc.` it works fine, but my query with the `$_GET`s gives me the error:

```
Unknown column 'myfullname' in 'field list'
```

Why would this be happening? How do I fix this? I don't normally do PHP/MySQL so I'm not too familiar.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize user input!!!

Comment: beware of sql injections - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Also, never use `$_GET` for database inserts.  Always use `$_POST`.  Last thing you need is a webcrawler bot tampering with your database.

Comment: The reason I'm using $_GET is so I can pass in a url string via an iPhone app I'm developing

Comment: @Chris: are you not able to craft headers from your app?  See: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/ for a basic POST example.  Ignore the code examples if it doesn't apply, focus on the header examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need quotes around all the variables:

```
// Sanitize with mysql_real_escape_string()
$name = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['fullname']);
$username = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['password']);
$gender = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['gender']);

// Escaped values can be interpolated in the double-quoted string.
$query = "INSERT INTO main (name, username, password,gender) VALUES ('$name','$username','$password','$gender');";
```

Since you are using a double-quoted string, you can simply include the variables in the string surrounded by single-quotes to be correctly interpolated, rather than concatenating them in with `.`  Not everyone agrees with the practice of interpolating variables in double-quoted strings, but it adds a lot of readability for a case like this, and might have made it easier to debug.

Comment: Damn you somehow beat me to the answer by a few seconds. *shakes fist* :p

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. The single and double quotes throw me off

Answer (score 4):

Place single quotes around your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). You never want to allow for direct insertion of variables provided by a GET or POST request without first escaping them to protect against SQL errors or [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). What you're doing is extremely risky.

Answer (score 0):

Next to sanitizing input, you can also parametrize your query:

```
$vars = array('fullname', 'username', 'password', 'gender');
$query = "INSERT INTO main (name, username, password, gender) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');";
$source = $_GET;

$vals = array_intersect_key($source, array_flip($vars));
if (count($vals) !== count($vars)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid Request, missing variables: '.implode(', ', array_keys(array_diff_key(array_flip($vars), $source))));
}

if (!mysql_query(vsprintf($query, array_map('mysql_reaL_escape_string', $vals)))) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Database Error: '.mysql_error());
}
```

This is just some quick written example, you should consider using mysqli instead of mysql (see [*Choosing an API<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) ) and it's recommended to take a look at [the PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).